# Add xvfb screen to docker image permanently.

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need permanently mount screen by Xvfb to docker image file. I found one solution, but it does not fully satisfy me, I want to have cleaner file and no log messages from xvfb in terminal.

```
ENV DISPLAY=:1.0 
CMD export DISPLAY
```

And this should be the last line of dockerfile or screen willn't  be mounted:

```
CMD Xvfb :1 -screen 0  1920x1080x16 &> xvfb.log  & \
    /bin/bash
```

I tried to use `RUN` instead of `CMD` and separation in two commands. This is not working.
The questions are how separate last line in two and fix problem with log.

Comment: can you show your Dockerfile and your `docker run` command? By the way, `ENV DISPLAY=:1.0`in a Dockerfile has the same meaning as `export DISPLAY` The last line of a Dockerfile is usually a CMD or ENTRYPOINT, because this is what is run. the `RUN` command is different

Comment: Before this 3 lines there is some code for installing several packages. I know that `CMD` and `RUN` are different but how to save settings to xvfb? Because in this case it is more like container initialization script. I am running container without any parameters for initializing any kind of program because in this case it will run container without screen.

Comment: you have to do in the Dockerfile RUN the same things you do in a Linux terminal.

Comment: But in this case it doesn't working. It does not creating screen.

Comment: Can you post the command and the  error message?

Comment: There is no error, you running container and it doesn't have screen. If you will type in container terminal `Xvfb :1 -screen 0  1920x1080x16 &> xvfb.log` you will get screen and it will work correctly with logging messages from xvfb to log file instead of posting log to terminal.